# Cannot upload more than 1mb using php mail function

Tags: php, smtp

I have a problem sending attachment file using php mail. If it is less than 1Mb it sends to mail as an attachment but if it is more than 1Mb it also sends but the file is broken and it's size is 0kb.

I have tried to modify my php.ini

```
upload_max_filesize=20M
post_max_size=10M
```

but nothing happens still broken images. I know it's much ok to use a php library but i'd like to know how to do it using php mail(). I'm using my localhost and my smtp server is gmail .thank you in advance.

Comment: have you restart your apache server or wamp server?

Comment: Yes, ive restart my apache already

Answer (score 0):

Check your `uploaded file size` using [ini_get()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php) in your `php script` like,

```
echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize').'<br/>';
ini_set("upload_max_filesize","20M");// if it is less than 1M then set to 20M
```

Comment: I'd echo it and it was 2m, I'll try your code and comment again what happen thank you

Comment: I'v change my upload max size to 20M but still i can send an attachment more than 1Mb. Any suggestions Rohan Kumar

Answer (score 0):

please read this 2 manuals for help

```
 http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php
```

and this

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php
```